# JRuby - query result is converted to String instead of Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jdbc, activerecord, jruby, jrubyonrails

```
activerecord 4.2.11.1
activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.3.25
activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter 1.3.25
jdbc-postgres 9.4.1206
```

The following method call returns a Date when using **ruby 2.3.3** but returns a String when using **JRuby-9.1.17.0** with activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter :

```
2.3.3 :017 > Table.select('now() as date').first.date
  Table Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  now() as date FROM "tables"  ORDER BY "tables"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => 2019-05-17 03:46:52 UTC
```

```
jruby-9.1.17.0 :002 > Table.select('now() as date').first.date
  Table Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  now() as date FROM "tables"  ORDER BY "tables"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => "2019-05-17 03:48:57.572526+00"
```

**This only happens if the selected attribute does not exist in the database:**

```
2.3.3 :012 > Table.select(:created_at).first.created_at
  Table Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "tables"."created_at" FROM "tables"  ORDER BY "tables"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => Wed, 25 Sep 2013 14:26:17 -03 -03:00
```

```
jruby-9.1.17.0 :019 > Table.select(:created_at).first.created_at
  Table Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "tables"."created_at" FROM "tables"  ORDER BY "tables"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => Wed, 25 Sep 2013 14:26:17 -03 -03:00
```

This happens with either WebRick or Tomcat 7. This error does not occur with the same version of activerecord-jdbc-adapter if using Active Record 4.0 or 4.1. Upgrading to latest jruby-9.2.7.0 did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

seems like a compatibility bug in AR-JDBC, at this point likely a won't fix as AR 4.2 also isn't supported.

you should try upgrading to 5.x if this is an issue or try resolving the problem and submit a PR ...

as a last resort try setting `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::JdbcConnection.raw_date_time = true` (altough I think its already `true`when running on AR 4.2)

Comment: Hello Kares. In fact with Rails 4.0 raw_date_time is nil, and it behaves correctly. With rails 4.2 raw_date_time is true, and it behaves correctly except for the case I mentioned in the post. But if I change it to false then it works for this case.

Comment: What does raw_date_time? == true mean ?

Comment: it might break other cases though, not exactly sure at this point but it was added around 4.x/4.2 support so there's a reason it must relate to AR compatibility esp. if its `true` on 4.2 ... you can try running some tests and also other adapters such as MySQL

Answer (score 0):

as @kares noted, this look like a bug, also it is related to the configuration `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::JdbcConnection.raw_date_time`. Its seems like if it is set to true the method call below returns a String, otherwise it returns a Time instance:

```
Locatario.select('now() as date').first.date
```

I have checked this behaviour with 3 versions of `active_record`:

```
Rails 3.2
    default raw_date_time? == true
    Table.select('now() as date').first.date
        Ruby: returns String
        JRuby: returns String
Rails 4.0/4.1
    default raw_date_time? == nil
    Table.select('now() as date').first.date
        Ruby: returns Time
        JRuby: returns Time
Rails 4.2
    default raw_date_time? == true
    Table.select('now() as date').first.date
        Ruby: returns Time
        JRuby: returns String
```

So, it looks like to emulate `active_record >= 4.0` the gem `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` should use `raw_date_time = false`, because it should return a Time instance with the method call in question. As a workaround I created a file with the following content under initializers:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == "java" && Rails::VERSION::STRING.starts_with?("4.2.") 
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::JdbcConnection.raw_date_time = false
end
```